# A way to block rich media (flash) ads from changing CSS elements on a page?

Tags: css, flash, code-injection, ads

I use display advertising on my site and I noticed certain expandable ads (ads that expand when you roll over them) changes some of the elements on my page by adding the code "visibility: hidden" as inline CSS.  This results in text boxes and other content disappearing when the ad loads.  Other than simply disabling the offending ad (not a good solution since I never know what other ads might be causing problems or not), is there a way to block ads from injecting CSS instructions into my site like this?  Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the flash add is using the ExternalInterface feature in flash to pipe javascript to your page:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

The easiest way to make sure this doesn't happen is to set allowScriptAccess to false on your object tag where the ad is embedded:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16494.html

If you need the functionality that require allowScriptAccess (navigateToUrl comes to mind) then things get a little bit more complicated :-)

Comment: wow, embedded flash can run JS on your page? i don't like that...especially if allowScriptAccess defaults to true

Comment: It defaults to false, obviously (that would be a massive security risk otherwise!). I'm not sure which ad network he is using but probably not a good one if they set allowScriptAccess to true in the code they provide.

Comment: Why do you say that navigateToUrl requires allowScriptAccess? I thought that only applied if you're using `javascript:foo();` style content as your URL, which is a bad practice anyway.

Comment: It's Burst Media, one of the largest ad networks around.  It only happens with a specific ad from Rice Krispies, but the only way I was able to stop it from injecting "visibility: hidden" into my <input>...</input> tags was to simply disable the campaign.  I was hoping for a way to prevent this for any type of ad that tries to do the same thing though.  I checked my ad code for Burst and I don't see anything indicating allowScriptSccess being set to true. Its just basic javascript code given by the network (sort of like Google Adsense)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what code is the offending ad injecting? You could use firebug to monitor what's coming down with the ad.  If it's just a swf, I would be interested to know if they're using the allowScriptAccess tag, or just pulling down a global javascript in the ad code.  If it's from the swf, there are still a few tricks left :-> $(function() {
  $("object param[name='allowScriptAccess']").attr('allowScriptAccess', 'sameDomain');
  $("object embed").attr('allowScriptAccess', 'sameDomain');
 });